# ThreadGuard or ThreadLocal for Selenium grid thread concurrency issues?

Tags: selenium, grid, selenium-chromedriver, thread-local

Which one is better - ThreadGuard or ThreadLocal for Selenium grid thread concurrency issues?

Comment: Can provide more details such as the language binding you are using, how you are achieving multithreading and what problems you are seeing?

Comment: We are using java have implemented it as follows :-ThreadLocal<WebDriver> threadLocalDriver = null;
    threadLocalDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
    threadLocalDriver.set(
    ThreadGuard.protect(new RemoteWebDriverWithScreenshot(new URL(
      hub_URL), browserCapabilities)));
    driver = threadLocalDriver.get();

Answer (score 0):

ThreadGuard will throw exception if it get invoked by 2 threads.
https://github.com/pilwon/selenium-webdriver/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ThreadGuard.java
It will not safeguard you from abusing webdriver with multiple threads.  But throws exception when you do so. 
Hope it helps.